# using sound fonts on xmplay

Tags: windows, audio, midi, xmplay

I am trying to install a small sound font for XMPlay. This far, I have downloaded a harmonica font and installed it in the config menu, by clicking in the add button on the top of the dialog; but somehow it does not play at all. Are there any other configuration options I am missing?

See figure below:

[image: configuration menu]

I am using the standard input plugin as shown below.

[image: input decoders]

Comment: Make sure you use the right midi decoder plugin. This config page is for one of the installed midi plugins, but if you use another one for playback, these settings are not used.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the trick is to select the font on the menu, and then assign the font to the 000 preset, by double clicking on the 000 slot on the right panel.

[image: sound font selection menu]

So that the panel displays the font in the 000 preset.

[image: desired font in the 000 preset]